Как сохранить выделенную строку с определенным цветом в dgv?
У меня есть dgv и кнопка, я выделяю нужную мне строку в dgv, нажимаю на кнопку и цвет фона в строке меняется, далее нажимаю на сохранить и выхожу из программы, вхожу обратно в программу и цвет который я изменил он не меняется остается тем же каким и был раньше, помогите пожалуйста
код кнопки:
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
dgv[i, dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

код кнопки сохранить:
XMLFile.Save(Data, "DataBase.xml");
MessageBox.Show("Вы успешно сохранили запись!", "Информация", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
MessageBoxIcon.Information);

код класса XMLFile.cs:
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


public class XMLFile
{
static XmlSerializer formatter;

/// <summary>
/// Сохраняем документ
/// </summary>
public static void Save<T>(T item, string path)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        formatter.Serialize(fs, item);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Загружаем документ
/// </summary>
public static T Load<T>(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
}


Не вижу обратного (чтения данных из файла и установку цвета, если данные есть в файле). Также не вижу свяжи между dgv и Data, из-за чего удаленно понять что вы там сохраняете, ну...., невозможно.

Спасибо за комментарий

XMLFile.Save(Data - что такое Data?
